# nodejs checking if url follows a valid format

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project on freecodecamp and I think it works as expected but I do not pass 1 test.

```
If you pass an invalid URL that doesn't follow the valid http://www.example.com format, the JSON response will contain { error: 'invalid url' }
```

This is the test I do not pass.
And down is my code

```
async function httpAddShortUrl(req, res) {
const input = req.body;

const isValid = await stringIsAValidUrl(input.url);

if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'invalid url'
    })
}

return res.status(200).json(addNewUrl(input.url));}
```

```
async function stringIsAValidUrl(url) {
    let hostname = '';

    try {
        hostname = new URL(url).hostname;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        return await dns.lookup(hostname);
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, I need to mention that inside the `stringIsAValidUrl` function I am using dns promises.

Comment: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/url-shortener-getting-final-test-to-pass/430694 this has the exact problem and solution

Comment: I already checked that post and tried to use some code from there. It did not work also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your function something like this:

```js
function stringIsAValidUrl(url) {

    const urlRegex = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/;
    return urlRegex.test(url);
}
console.log(stringIsAValidUrl("https://www.example.com"));
console.log(stringIsAValidUrl("www.example.com"));
console.log(stringIsAValidUrl("http://www.goo le.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed it but still does not work.

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to validate? Isn't it `"https://www.example.com"`?

Comment: No, there are some urls from their tests. Actually, I found the problem and from my perspective it is not my fault. I removed the status codes from the responses and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code not working was coming from status codes. I removed the status codes from the responses and now it works. Thank you all for trying to help me.